# Cannot save Django Session with multiple IP in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, session

This is my first StackOverflow question. Please be kind :-)

For a private Django project with legacy code, I'm using PostgreSQL as database.

Last weekend, a user tried to register from behind a proxy, so the [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format) HTTP header contained more than one IP address.

For certain reasons, I needed to subclass [SessionBase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase) from django.contrib.sessions.backends.base to apply custom logic.

In the save method of it, a new Session object is prepared for saving. Thereby I'm assigning `self.ip` to the `ip` field. Whenever a proxy is involved, multiple IPs are in that value. PostgreSQL cannot handle that in an `inet`-field and I'd opt to not to alter to a `varchar`-field if possible.

Is there anything else I can do to make Django + PostgreSQL work with multiple IPs in sessions?

Comment: IPs cannot be used to identify a user, and it's beyond trivial to forge the forwarded header.

Comment: Just clean up the header so it only contains a single IP address. Pick the first or last - it doesn't really matter. As Marc B says it's not really useful from an auth point of view.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I tried to pick one IP by assigning `ip=self.ip.split(',')[0]` on Session, but that didn't do the trick. I don't get errors. But I'm not logged in either. I get redirected to the URL passed via ?next=, but have no session or any hint.